# MarkLogic Path Range Indexes as App Builder facets

Tags: marklogic

I am setting up some **Path Range Indexes** in a MarkLogic document database. The goal is to have them available as facets in an App Builder generated application.

These indexes are created successfully, I can even query them using the cts:path-range-query function.

However I don't see how to add them as facets using the App Builder. This is strange because other range indexes such as the **Element Range** work fine, but it seems that Path Range Indexes don't show up as a **source index**.

Is it a known limitation or I forgot to do something specific to the **Path Range Indexes**? Should it be configured through the "Custom XML Options"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UI doesn't know about Path Range Indexes. You may be able to define the constraint in Custom XML Options, but it still won't show up on that first panel. What you'll need to do is edit the code to add that one yourself. I did a blog post on [capturing the code & config working with the Roxy Deployer](http://blog.davidcassel.net/2013/08/capturing-an-app-building-application-with-roxy/).

Once you have the code, take a look through the [Extending Applications Built with Application Builder](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-builder/custom) chapter of the [App Builder Developer's Guide](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-builder).